# pywinauto print_control_identifiers() doesn't work

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, automation, pywinauto

Does anybody know the reason why I can't see full tree for Adobe AIR Setup Installer

My code is: * for unknown reason I can not start app and see it, I need first start it, then check process ID, and after use *"connect(process=ID)"* or I have this error:

> pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'best_match':
>   'AdobeAIRSetup', 'backend': 'uia', 'process': 3480}

```
#app = Application(backend='uia').start(r'AdobeAIRInstaller.exe')

app = Application().connect(process=9880) 
app.AdobeAIRSetup.print_control_identifiers()
```

After that I can see result:

> Control Identifiers:
>
> ApolloRuntimeContentWindow - 'Adobe AIR Setup'    (L1163, T107, R1883,
>   B754) ['ApolloRuntimeContentWindow', 'Adobe AIR
>   SetupApolloRuntimeContentWindow', 'Adobe AIR Setup']
>   child_window(title="Adobe AIR Setup",
>   class_name="ApolloRuntimeContentWindow")

But there are no "I Agree" and "Cancel" button, that is why I can not click on it !

[image: Adobe Setup Windows]

[image: Inspect I can see 2 buttons]

[image]

Comment: You have to use Application(backend=“uia”) for connect as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks, its works now! But I still can not start App in regular way - Every time have pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError

Comment: What is wrong in this call - "app = Application(backend='uia').start(r'AdobeAIRInstaller.exe')"

Comment: start() method should work. Probably next line is not working. You can print app.process and compare with PID in Task Manager. Maybe installer spawns additional process with the GUI. Then you have to start and then connect anyway.

Comment: Compared, its different ! So in this case, there is no way to automate it ? Can I receive somehow PID after start (method) in automated way?

Comment: This installer regenerated 2 PID processes with the same name, pls see attach, "app.AdobeAIRInstaller.print_control_identifiers()" - this command doesn't work also!

Comment: Ok, found solution with "import psutil" to obtain PID

Comment: Can you post this solution as an answer and accept it? I would like to think about automatic detection of spawned process in pywinauto.

Comment: Yes, sure. Vasily I have another issue, in diff installer, pywinauto doesn't see all buttons with the same PID, in Inspector I can see, but not in print_control_identifiers(). Should I create a new question? or we can move next here?

Comment: Yes, please create a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution with "import psutil" will help to obtain PID and send it to connect method!

```
from pywinauto import Application, Desktop

import psutil


PROCNAME = "Adobe AIR Installer.exe"
app = Application(backend='uia').start(r'AdobeAIRInstaller.exe')
apploaded = False


while apploaded == False:
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
            print(proc.pid)
            app = Application(backend='uia').connect(process=proc.pid)
            apploaded = True
```

Comment: You have simple way to do this with pywinauto: `app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path=PROCNAME, timeout=5)` That's it! :)